# Android alerts: how to upgrade AlertDialog from old style (black) to new style (white)?

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

I am currently updating a old app. The alerts have an old style (quite ugly), with a black background. How to have the new white style ? (nota: it seems that using recent params in Gradle like compileSdkVersion 25, buildToolsVersion "25.0.2", targetSdkVersion 22 is not enough)

Note that my circular ProgressBars are also 'old style'.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Presumably, change your app's theme.

Comment: I don't think that it is the problem. My circular ProgressBars are also old style...

Comment: `ProgressBar` is also controlled by the theme. Please provide a [mcve]. This would include: screenshots of what you think is "quite ugly"/"old style" and the code/resources used to create them.

Comment: The theme used in the 'application' tag of my app is   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" What should I choose instead to have a modern style compatible down to SDK 10? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The theme used in the 'application' tag of my app is android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

That is the original theme from Android 1.x/2.x. Themes affect many things, including the look of alert dialogs and `ProgressBar`.

> What should I choose instead to have a modern style compatible down to SDK 10?

Option #1: Leave it alone and live with it.

Option #2:

- Create `res/values-v13/styles.xml` and create a custom theme (e.g., `AppTheme`) that inherits from `@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`
- Create `res/values/styles.xml` and create a custom theme with the same name (e.g., `AppTheme`) that inherits from `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`
- Have your `<application>` use your custom theme (e.g., `AppTheme`)

This will adopt the Holo theme on API Level 13+ devices.

Option #3:

- Do everything from Option #2
- Also add `res/values-v21/styles.xml` and create a custom theme with the same name that inherits from `@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar`

This will adopt the Holo theme on API Level 13-20 devices and the Material theme on API Level 21+ devices.

Option #4: Rewrite your app to use `appcompat-v7` (`AppComaptActivity`, modified menu resources, etc.) and use a suitable `Theme.AppCompat`-based theme. This will give you the same look on all versions, at the cost of modifying all of your activities, all of your menu resources, adding the `appcompat-v7` dependency, and perhaps other changes as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed my manifest to android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" and increased minSDK to 14. And it works ! :) Thanks for your great explanations.

Comment: Actually, it works for the progressBars (which are now nice) but my alerts are still not so nice :) But that is ok like this... Thanks !